# ruby mysql2 equivalent of data_seek(n).fetch_hash

Tags: ruby, mysql2

What is the equivalent statement in mysql2 for this

```
result = MYSQL.query('SELECT cache_amount_with_discount_and_tax FROM t_payment WHERE organization_id = 1 AND receipt_id = '+param['receipt_id'].to_s).data_seek(3).fetch_hash

// where MYSQL is the original MYSQL client
```

I'm new to ruby and still trying to wrap my ahead around the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `mysql2` supports `data_seek`, but you can use SQL native `OFFSET`, which is even better since it limits the amount transfered to the client in the first place. `mysql2` returns rows as hashes by default, so that's a non-issue. So...

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT cache_amount_with_discount_and_tax
  FROM t_payment
  WHERE organization_id = 1
    AND receipt_id = #{client.escape(param['receipt_id'])}
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
SQL
result = client.query(sql, as: :hash, symbolize_keys: false)
hash_row = result.first
```

The options I have given (`as: :hash, symbolize_keys: false`) are default, and can be left off unless you have changed the defaults; or you can mess with them to customise your result (e.g. having symbolic column keys instead of strings).

Also, note the `client.escape` bit. Never, ever, feed raw user input into an SQL statement, or [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) might be your next client.

Even better would be using an abstraction library that provides prepared statement and parameter binding support, like [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel).